# JQuery not running after a php redirect

Tags: php, jquery

This is probably really simple, but I can't seem to figure it out. I am submitting a php form and when the form has completed all the actions (ie submitting items to the database) the form then redirects to see all the 'comments'.

On this comment page I have a jQuery run chapter select drop down. When the page is first redirected the drop down does not work, it will not change between chapters. Now when I reload the page and select a chapter from the drop down it works fine.

Is there something I am doing wrong or is there a way to trigger these functions on page load?

My JQuery looks like this for the drop down and this does work after refreshing the page

```
$(document).ready(function () {

 $('#sortReviews').change(function () {
            var review = $(this).val();
            var allReviews = review.split('/')[1];
            if (allReviews == "allreviews") {
                $(location).attr('href', 'http://writeyourfiction.com/reviews/' + review)
            } else {
                $(location).attr('href', '/chapterReviews/' + review)
            }
        });
 });
```

and my redirect is just a simple codeigniter redirect

```
redirect('chapterComments/'.$story_id.'/'.$chapter_id);
```

Any help would be wonderful!

Comment: Are you sure this is what you want `$(location)`?

Comment: yes, that is how I am changing the page within jquery and that works. My problem is after the php redirects.

Comment: value of location is ?????

Comment: @JOELEE redirect('chapterComments/'.$story_id.'/'.$chapter_id); this is what redirects and then my jQuery does not work.

Comment: Is there some reason you are calling `$(location).attr('href', '/chapterReviews/' + review)` rather than the `redirect` function in your change event handler ? Or for that matter, calling `window.location = 'http://chapterReviews/' + review;` ?

Comment: @DomDay What redirect function? And I am not using window.location because through research and experience $(location) is faster and in fact some tutorials I have read warn against using window.location because it is slowly become invalid.

Comment: nevermind, I misread your post as using a js function call named `redirect` rather than a php call. As for what the best method is, I'm fairly sure `window.location.assign()` is a w3c standard, and won't go away any time soon

Comment: @DomDay I guess at the end of the day they both do the same thing. Those $('location')'s are working and at this point if it works then it works. haha I've spent way too much time on this...

Comment: for troubleshooting, maybe pop in a `console.log("handler:change fired")` into your change event and see if the code is executing. At least this will tell you if the problem is the handler or the redirect

Answer (score 0):

You should use `$(document).ready(../*your code*/..)` Instead Of `$('#sortReviews').change`

Comment: I have a  $(document).ready at the top of my jQuery file. I just did not post that here as I was posting a snippet of my jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

add some function to refresh it.. and call it on document ready and when your pick list onChange:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#sortReviews').change(function () {
        refresh();
    });
    refresh();
});


function refresh(){
    var review = $(this).val();
    var allReviews = review.split('/')[1];
    if (allReviews == "allreviews") {
        $(location).attr('href', 'http://writeyourfiction.com/reviews/' + review)
    } else {
        $(location).attr('href', '/chapterReviews/' + review)
    }
 }
```

Comment: This is doing the same thing. After I refresh the page it works, but not after the php redirect. And this is purely out of ignorance, but why would putting the code within a function refresh the page?

Comment: you sure redirect to same page?

Comment: yes, my php is redirecting to the right page and then I try and choose a chapter and the jQuery is not working.

Comment: you need to ensure that jquery on document ready works.. may be you alert or log something in your document ready function.

Comment: My document.ready is working. I am using jQuery on previous pages and other spots on the page.

Comment: okay next step is to ensure your refresh function working. you can alert in begining and end of function.. does it works perfectly? any error show in console?

Comment: I have no errors, but the alert does not work in the function after the refresh, but if I refresh the page it does.

Comment: It seems I just figured it out. As soon as I took this code out of document.ready it works fine. Maybe, the document.ready was taking too long to be ready?

Comment: i think the document ready function just fine since u said that alert in document ready is works. But if you still want to prove you can log time in console..

Answer (score 0):

I think, this was due to not using full URL redirection in jquery.

Just try this one.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

 $('#sortReviews').change(function () {

            var review = $(this).val();
            var allReviews = review.split('/')[1];
            var href ; 

            if (allReviews == "allreviews") {

                href = 'http://writeyourfiction.com/reviews/' + review ;

            } else {

                href = 'http://writeyourfiction.com/chapterReviews/' + review ;

            }

            location.replace(href);

        });

 });
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work because it just was not loading right away. I tried a few things and as soon as I took it out of the document.ready it worked. Strange, but true. I guess the document.ready just was not loading immediately like I needed it to and instead it was taking up to five minutes to run.

Comment: Could you please provide the demo link where you are getting error ?

Comment: I did end up fixing this issue by taking the one function out of the document.ready. I would love to provide a demo link, but I cannot do a jsfiddle since it is so intertwined in php.